# jQuery location.reload() and start function()

Tags: jquery, location, reload

i need help in function location.reload()

My code:

```
$('.class').on('click', function(){
location.reload();
alert("yea");
});
```

Problem is big, because webrowser first show alert "yea" and next to reload page.. I need call function when location end reload.

Someone can help me?

Comment: You want after reload show "yea"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) or `cookies` like,

```
$('.class').on('click', function(){
   localStorage.setItem('reload',1); // set the reload key for alert
   location.reload();
});
if(localStorage.getItem('reload') && localStorage.getItem('reload')==1){ // if you get the key and ==`1
   localStorage.removeItem('reload'); // remove the key, to prevent next alert
   alert("yea"); // alert first time
}
```

Also read [storages](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)